# How to place cols at the center of a row in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to create a grid using MaterializeCSS, and should place each `col` at the center of `row`, but now the `cols` all start from left of `row`.

And I add a `display:flex` into `row`, but it actually breaks the responsiveness, that means if I squeeze the width of my browser, I observe no responsiveness of the `row & col`.

Code as follows, please help.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="border:1px solid black;display:flex">
        <div class="col s12 m3">
          abc
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m3">
          abc
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m3">
          abc
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to use an offset on the first col, but your maths is a little off.

Materialize uses a 12 column grid and % based layout, not flex. Setting size-3 on a column (s3, m3, l3) says 'take up 25%', because 12/3 is 4, or 25%.

So in your scenario, your content is 75% of the container - and to center this using the grid, you'd need 12.5% either side. Not possible.

Three solutions:

**1. Force your 3 columns to take up all available space equally:**

`<div class="col s12 m4"></div>`

`<div class="col s12 m4"></div>`

`<div class="col s12 m4"></div>`

**2. Use an offset**

This means shrinking your content columns down from 3 (25%) to 2 (16.7%). This is so we can have even space either side - an offset of 3 columns, and then empty space the other side.

`<div class="col s12 m2 offset-m3"></div>`

`<div class="col s12 m2"></div>`

`<div class="col s12 m2"></div>`

**4. Use flex and a media query.**

The Materialize grid uses % and margin:auto for spacing. We'd need to override this when we hit the m breakpoint (> 600px).

```
.flex-row {
  @media (min-width:600px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    > .col.m3 {
      margin-left:0;
    }
  }
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/LYpBLbw).

https://materializecss.com/grid.html#offsets

Comment: why it's so complicated in MaterializeCSS? And typically a `display:flex; justify-content:space-around` would work, right?

Comment: It’s not complicated if you know how to use it - and there’s no need to use extra css to make responsive grids. Materialize doesn’t use flex, it uses a % based layout, which doesn’t mix great with flex out of the box. You can use flex in this way, but you’d need a media query to take it off at smaller screen sizes. I’ll put together a pen to demonstrate.